# How can I delete unused data blocks from my Blender Project?

Tags: blend-files

I have a project that's 101 megabytes (it's packed).  I need it to be under 100 megabytes to upload it to a renderfarm I'm using.  There are several large image texture files within the project that I know I don't need, but they have false users, so I can't delete them.  How do I get rid of them?

(In the past, I know there was a Shift+F4 data block viewer or something, but that's gone as far as I know post 2.6)

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks guys!

Comment: This is a great question, Wilhelm. I marked it as a duplicate of another question though, since you seem to be asking the same thing. We want to try not to split answers between two questions if we can avoid it.

Comment: This was asked and answered already, the title is just a bit different. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file