# How to delete textures from the UV image editor list

Tags: texturing

[image]
In my UV image editor I have a few textures, that I don't use anymore.
I tried to delete these from the list there, by clicking on the minus button, the delete key. ( - ) 
but nothing got deleted. 
I saved the project and reopened , but that didn't help anything,
the files are still there, I can click a hundred times on the delete button, it won't delete. 
The list is located right between to the image menu and the plus button in the UV image editor.

Is there a way to get these textures out of my list ? Not all of them but just one or a few.

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/deleting-unused-textures-from-blender-using-python

Comment: I noticed your edit, simply follow the instructions on the marked duplicate. `Shift` click the `X` and save and reopen.

Comment: yes , it worked out great, sorry again for beginners questions. i try to figure out most obvious things, LOL.