# Delete file names from search line

Tags: texturing

How to delete these Warehouse.jpg names from the list?
I want to pack extra files, but get errors because these files don't exist

I use X sign, but no result
[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/delete-all-unused-textures-from-blender-using-python

Comment: Yes, this helped even without Python!