# Delete all unused TEXTURES at once?

Tags: texturing

I have one blender save file that is basically just a render scene where I bake renders of models so they all have the same lighting and orientation. Naturally i accumulate a lot of textures over time and wanted to know if there is an easy was to instantly remove all unused textures at once.

I know i can delete all materials with one click, but the textures stay behind.
I also know how i can delete textures one by one, but that takes too long.

Is there even a way to effectively delete all textures that are not used at once? I'd even be happy if i could delete all textures, even if they were used.

Comment: This question has a solution with a python script, I'm not sure if there's another way to do it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/delete-all-unused-textures-from-blender-using-python

Comment: You can [purge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102620/935) orphaned data in the outliner, this is a two step process, removing materials leaves images orphaned which can then be purged.

Comment: @ScottMilner I was talking about textures, not materials. But the outliner option worked. Thank you sambler.

Comment: @MrFunreal Both unused textures and materials (and all unused datablocks) are removed the same way

Comment: @ScottMilner While that answer is applicable, This technically isn't a duplicate. One is about Textures and the other is about materials.

Comment: The way suggested in that discussion is about unlinking materials, saving and reopening. that works FOR MATERIALS. The textures however stay behind, i already stated that.
anyways. my problem has been solved by going to the orphan data tab and doing it via that.