# Is it possible to pack a sequence of images into a .blend file?

Tags: blend-files, data-blocks

I want to pack an animated texture (a sequence of images) into a .blend file, but for some reason, I can't do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Related: [How do I completely remove an image from my .blend file?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course pack many image data blocks,
but you can't pack the frames of an image where the **Source** is set to **Image Sequence**.