# Delete all materials on all meshes and only add one default material to all meshes?

Tags: mesh, materials

I want to delete all materials on all meshes and only add one default material to all meshes? I tried the "Copy Material to Others", but it's not working.

I still have some materials somewhere. Like this in the box:
[image: Materials]

**EDIT:** OK, I got it now. The problem was, that some objects were hidden. So the "Copy Material to Others" didn't worked. When you open the file, then first press "Alt + H" to unhide all objects. Then do the "Copy Material to Others". Save file and open it again.

Comment: What exactly is "not working" with *Copy Materials To Others* ? It does what is written in your first sentence.

Comment: I know this link. I tried that. It's the reason why I said, that "Copy Material to Others" is not working. I selected one object. Then I did this in the 3d view toolbar "Select > Select All by Type > Mesh". Then I deleted all materials. I added only one material. Then I clicked "Copy Material to Others". So, why I have this materials in the box?

Comment: @Johnny I think this addon will help you a video tutorial

Comment: @atek which addon?

Comment: "Then I deleted all materials" - how did you deleted them ? Which materials did you delete ? "I added only one material" - where did you add it ? How do your actions differ from [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S87e2.gif) ?

Comment: @Johnny name of the addon is orphan cleanup download from here http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.in/2013/12/addon-orphan-cleanup.html

Comment: This is, how I deleted it. I also clicked "Shift" key. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file

Comment: This plugin also don't work. I found, that this addon is included in blender 2.78a as "orphan slayer".