# Deleting an unwanted UV mapping and Images

Tags: uv

Just starting to get into Blender and was doing quite well.  This has me stumped though I have two UV spaces attached to an object.

Base and Base.001 and I cannot figure out how to get rid of one!  Worse in my attempts I have created lots of images and I can't get rid of those either.  Where do they go and how do you get rid of them?

These are all black and white as try as I may I cannot paint any colour inside the UV windows.  That I can sort by editing in GIMP, can see no logic as to why it will not work though :-(

Please point me in the right direction if you can.

Comment: Select the object then select "Object Data" (The icon is a triangle with dots on the three corners). Scroll down to "UV Maps". Select the UV Map you want to delete and press the "-" (Minus) button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I completely remove an image from my .blend file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file)