# How do i unlink a texture from a material?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, unity

I applied a texture via uv mapping editor and node editor for reference, did the job, deleted the image texture node, unticked "use nodes" box, removed the texture from uv mapping editor and that texture still affects the material. When i import the .blend file to unity, the material gets renamed from "wood" to "wood_woodDoor_jpg". I notice that the texture doesnt have a 0 next to it in uv mapping editor and that when i reopen the project, it stays there. How do i  remove this texture from my project?
[image]
[image]

I did the exact same thing before with no problem. This time around, maybe i did something in a wrong order?

I even selected this in Unity:

[image]

Comment: The texture probably was associated with another material (like those present in the selected object materials) and thus still had a user until you explicitly deleted it by choosing it from the list and pressing Shift+x button.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [How do I completely remove an image from my .blend file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101/45641)

Apparently I had to add the texture to the UV map editor *again* and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> the X button to remove that texture from my project.