# How to remove unwanted textures to save memory

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, memory-management

I have two textures in Blender that are for a desk I am modeling. Each texture is 4K quality and takes up a ton of memory. I only have 4GB of memory on my computer, so I can't render an image of my scene. I decided that I would use an HD quality texture instead of a 4K, but I can not replace or remove textures from my texture list in Blender. Is there a way I can do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not worry about all the images in your blend file. If they are not used in the render they will not effect the memory. Simply change the images out for the smaller ones and try to render again (make sure your nodes are not using the large image anywhere).

To remove the images from the blend file <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> on the X in the image datablock. (Image from the UV Editor header)
[image: UV Editor header]
[How do I completely remove an image from my .blend file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100/2217)

If you still are out of memory, then you are going to have to look at you geometry. Do you have any hidden geometry? Subdivision surface jacking up the poly count? Many of the same objects not sharing a datablock.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me.