# Why can't I delete this texture slot?

Tags: texturing, interface

I can't delete a texture slot. For some reason I don't have the X button there or minus. There's not even a delete option and I don't know what else I can do.

Solved: After a few hours i found an answer, it was just holding a shift while selecting unlinking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove unwanted textures to save memory](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161039/how-to-remove-unwanted-textures-to-save-memory)

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please add some images to your question, so it's more clear. Without that, it's just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to delete it in edit mode it won't let you. Make sure you're in Object mode.